# How to retrieve SharePoint webpage code(html) or Scrape a sharepoint webpage?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, sharepoint-online

We are developing a bot in nodejs and as a requirement we need to dynamically fetch a webpage from Sharepoint online site webpages.
I tried using many api's such as https://[tenantName].com/sites/[xyzpage]/_api/web/$metadata.,i tried a lot other apis but most of them are for retrieving lists etc.

The following returns a lot of info which is irrelavant to webpage contents. Is there any api that returns webpage source code/html in the [xyzpage]

I tried webscraping tools but sharepoint online sites are protected so could work with it?is there any way to scrape protected pages with client id/secret?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You mean a simple http get request ?

Comment: yes get request through nodejs. when the website is password protected.

Comment: How is the website password protected ?

Comment: its our clients sharepoint page. where we need to dynamically retrieve info  from the webpage. The sharepoint website is private, not a public page like wikipedia. Users need to login with credentials to access the page.

Comment: Ok, and how does login works ?! user/email & password via plain formular, LDAP, HTTP basic auth?! Post more details

Comment: HTTP basic auth,it uses azure auth2.0 endpoint,where the client tenant is already registered. Sharepoint online doesnt support LDAP etc.  The problem is how do i scrape a website which is HTTP authenticated without using any credentials of valid users. I read about puppeteers module but thats for public websites.. also sharepoint online provides various client secret and client id (sharepoint add-in) to access list, i was wondering if not scrape could i use any existing api (which could get me a webpage/site within sharepoint collection with these client secret/id)

Comment: You cant, you have to login! There is no exeception. Why your client does not create a "scapper" user for this purpose ?

Comment: with a scrapper user,how can it be done? any documentation,module? to scrape http auth site from nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out how to scrape sharepoint site. Refer to microsoft docs sharepoint list scraping. Turns out all site/web infos are also treated as list in sharepoint. Sharepoint list api will fetch all the details from anywhere in sharepoint sites/web